# Remove spurious second root in a git repo

Tags: git

Somehow we have 2 roots in a git repo. One is what we expect, master and other branches. The other is a completely unrelated repo.

So, if I do `git checkout master`, I get what we expect. I've found the last commit hash for the odd root, and if I `git checkout ca992b28a` (for a headless checkout), I get this other random repo.

How do I remove it?
How do I find who committed it?
The commit is part of the https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-sagepay repo that a couple of my colleagues work on, but this is completely unrelated to the repo in question.

The commit points to a commit in 2016.
The presence of the commit in our repo is in the last 30 days.

[image: Sourcetree view of foreign root]

Comment: It sounds like someone accidentally pushed to the wrong repo then deleted the branch.  How did you find this if there's no branches or tags associated with it?

Comment: There are tags associated with these other commits. I use Sourcetree, and when I pull, I tick the "prune" and "tag" options (`--prune --tags`). It was then that I saw the new tags. The last tag (2.3.1) can be seen in the image above.

Comment: To to clarify, the issue is that you're seeing it, not that your repository is too large on disk or that there's sensitive data which must not stay in the repository?

Comment: The code is completely unrelated to this repo and does not belong to us. It is for another project that some of my colleagues contribute to. We would like to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like someone made a mistake and pushed some code to the wrong repository.  Git itself won't record who pushed, but some git based server software (such as gitlab) might keep a separate log.

Git doesn't make it easy to completely remove commits from a repository once they've been pushed.  But normally that's not a problem.  you only *usually* care about commit history which is referenced by a branch or tag.

In your case, you still have tags pointing at the unwanted history.

**Firstly** delete any tags pointing to unwanted history and double check for unwanted branches, deleting those too.  Make sure you delete both tags and branches on the remote repository not just your local copy.

**Then** If you are concerned that the commit history should not be stored at all in your repository (eg: it contains sensitive details) then you need to clear out the unused history completely.

I *believe* this can be done with `git gc --aggressive`.  [See here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc)

Answer (score 0):

To find all references to the new root,

```
git for-each-ref --contains=$thenewroot
```

To remove a history from your repo, the easy way (git will clean out the objects as they age), just delete the references to it:

```
git for-each-ref --contains=$thenewroot --format='delete %(refname)' \
| git update-ref --stdin
```

and the easiest native-git way to clean out all unreferenced objects from a repo Right Now if you can't wait for the aging is to do a full-amnesiac repack afterwards:

```
git repack -ad
```

but notice that clones don't get unreferenced objects anyway, so just deleting the bad refs from your published repo already means no future clones from that repo will get the objects in the unwanted history.